# JSF2.0 composite component calling set method for a custom datatype

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Greeting,
i have created a JSF composite component that takes an object of custom made class, and views its content, everything went good but i need the component to call the set method in the bean holding the custom class object.

Sample Example :

1- the component - componentTest.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="valueHolder" required="true" type="com.max.ValueHolder" />
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.valueHolder.value}" />
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

notice that the component use an attribute of a custom type :

```
<composite:attribute name="valueHolder" required="true" type="com.max.ValueHolder" />
```

2- the test page - default.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:max="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/max" >
     <h:body>       
        <h:form target="@self">      
            <max:componentTest valueHolder="#{user.valueHolder}" /> 
            <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{myBean.action}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

and finally the bean - MyBean.java :

```
package com.max;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.max.ValueHolder;

@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean{
    private ValueHolder valueHolder= new ValueHolder();

    public ValueHolder getValueHolder() {
        return valueHolder;
    }
    public void setValueHolder(ValueHolder valueHolder) {
        this.valueHolder = valueHolder;
    }

    public String action(){
        return "default";
    }
}
```

- My problem is that the method Mybean.setValueHolder() is not being called as the h:inputText is holding the value within the ValueHolder not the ValueHolder itself.

and i have tried setting the value with something like

```
<c:set var="cachedValueHolder" value="${cc.attrs.valueHolder}"/>
<a4j:ajax event="change" >
    <a4j:param value="#{cachedValueHolder}" assignTo="#{cc.attrs.valueHolder}" />
</a4j:ajax>
```

but it didnt work im not sure why!

Regards

Comment: Do you know about [cc:editableValueHolder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/cc/editableValueHolder.html)? See http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsf/jsf2TagLibrary/composite/editableValueHolder.html for one of many examples. Sounds like your `ValueHolder` should be one.

Comment: I'm not sure mabi, it seems to me that cc:editableValueHolder and cc:valueHolder are used to allow access of the internal components within the composite component to the outer page that uses the composite component, i'm not sure if i understood the cc:editableValueHolder and cc:valueHolder correctly or if i am missing something.